# Is the Pixel 7a GWKK3 is a locked or unlocked phone?

Tags: google, rom, bootloader-lock

I've tried to find if my new Pixel 7a GWKK3 is locked or unlocked by looking at its box. I have not opened it yet.

I could not figure out for sure if i can open it and install grapheneos on it.

Do you maybe know if it's a locked or unlocked?
How can I tell for sure?

Thank you.